# Extract first word from txt file before ending with "/" sign in linux which contains "db" word in txt line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have abc.txt file which contains two lines. I want to extract first word in line which contains `db` word in particular line.

abc.txt:

```
XYZ/db_abc.sql
ijkl/tables/table_name/tl_abc.sql
```

When I tried grep `grep "db" abc.txt` I am getting line which contains 'db' but I want to extract first word `XYZ` as output.

Output:

```
$ grep "db" abc.txt
XYZ/db_abc.sql
```

Expected Ouput:

```
XYZ
```

Similarly,When I tried grep `grep "tl" abc.txt` I am getting line which contains 'tl' but I want to extract third word `table_name` as output.

Output:

```
$ grep "tl" abc.txt
ijkl/tables/table_name/tl_abc.sql
```

Expected Output:

```
table_name
```

Comment: What to do it the string is found in first word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
$ awk -F / -v q=db '$0 ~ q { print $(NF-1) }' file
XYZ
```

```bash
$ awk -F / -v q=tl '$0 ~ q { print $(NF-1) }' file
table_name
```

These two `awk` commands are identical but are given different arguments to query for different expressions. Whatever string is assigned to the `awk` variable `q` on the command line is used as an extended regular expression and will be matched against each line in the given file(s).  When the expression matches a line, the 2nd field from the end is printed.  This is done by using the special variable `NF` (the number of fields on the current line) to calculate the field number of the penultimate field (`NF-1`). The utility delimits fields by slashes (as indicated by using `-F /`).

A variation of this that makes sure that the query pattern is only ever matched in the last field:

```bash
awk -F / -v q=tl '$NF ~ q { print $(NF-1) }' file
```

To additionally ensure that we only care about lines that end in `.sql`:

```bash
awk -F / -v q=tl '/\.sql$/ && $NF ~ q { print $(NF-1) }' file
```

Comment: Or just `awk -F/ '/db/{print $1}' file` and `awk -F/ '/tl/{print $3}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton I wanted it to be parametrised for ease of use, but yes, if they're happy with hard-coding the field number.

Comment: Understood, I just don't want the OP or other people reading this in future to think using `awk` **requires** that extra complexity compared to using `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

It would return you the whole line because that how grep works by default.
To extract a certian part of the sentence I would recommend you to use regex.

To extract `XYZ` out of the sentence you could use regex built like this:

```
grep -oP ".*(?=/db) abc.txt"
```

`-o` is to return only the lines that match the pattern.

`-P` is to search patterns using `Perl Regex`.

`.*` searches for any character other than `\n`

`(?=/db)` would say to look for everything that is behind the string that matches `/db` but stop the match once you get to the string itself. Meaning, to not include `/db` and anything beyond that.

Similarly to look for `table_name` we would need to apply a similar method.
We can either use regex like this:

```
grep -oP "(?<=tables/).*(?=/tl) abc.txt"
```

Which is kinda similar to the last grep but this time we added `(?<=tables/)`
which tells the grep to return us anything that comes after `tabels/` and before `/tl`.

We can do this also by using the `awk` command if you don't want to use RegEx.

To retrieve `XYZ` you could use:

```
grep "db" abc.txt | awk -F '/' '{ print $1 }'
```

So in this case the `grep` command will return us the full line but we use `awk` to split the line by the dilimiter `/` and return us the first part of the split line.

To retrieve `table_name` we can do:

```
grep "tl" abc.txt | awk -F '/' '{ print $3 }'
```

Which is very similar to the first command but in this case we need the 3rd part of the sentence.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `grep "db" abc.txt | awk -F '/' '{ print $1 }'` = `awk -F '/' '/db/{ print $1 }' abc.txt`